# Jumbotron not showing as grayish

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

My bootstrap jumbotron will not show a dark grayish background like what the docs show. Am I doing something wrong?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<br/>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Todo App</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple todo app that can help you keep track of your todos.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Create a new todo list</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing Bootstrap [`v4`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/) documentation but as per [`v5`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/jumbotron/) documentation you need to add classes like [`bg-light`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/background/) or `bg-dark`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<br/>
<div class="p-5 jumbotron bg-light">
  <h1 class="display-4">Todo App</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple todo app that can help you keep track of your todos.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Create a new todo list</a>
  </p>
</div>
```